# Django - view, url weirdness

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I've noticed a strange behavior with how Django is processing my url patterns.  A user should login and then be redirected to their profile page.  I also have the ability for a user to edit their profile.

Here are my URL patterns for one of my apps:

```
urlpatterns=patterns('student.views',
    (r'profile/$', login_required(profile,'student')),
    (r'editprofile/$', login_required(editprofile,'student')),
)
```

This is for an app called student.  If the user goes to /student/profile they should get the profile view.  If they go to /student/editprofile they should get the editprofile view.  I setup a function called login_required which does some checks on the user.  It's a little more complicated than I could handle with just annotations.

Here's login_required:

```
def login_required(view,user_type='common'):
    print 'Going to '+str(view)
    def new_view(request,*args,**kwargs):
        if(user_type == 'common'):
            perm = ''
        else:
            perm = user_type+'.is_'+user_type
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            messages.error(request,'You must be logged in.  Please log in.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        elif request.user.is_authenticated() and user_type != 'common' and not request.user.has_perm(perm):
            messages.error(request,'You must be an '+user_type+' to visit this page.  Please log in.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return view(request,*args,**kwargs)
    return new_view
```

Anyways, the weird thing is that, when I visit /student/profile, even though I get to the right page, login_required prints the following:

```
Going to <function profile at 0x03015DF0>
Going to <function editprofile at 0x03015BB0>
```

Why is it printing both?  Why is it trying to visit both?

Even weirder, when I try to visit /student/editprofile, the profile page is what loads and this is what's printed:

```
Going to <function profile at 0x02FCA370>
Going to <function editprofile at 0x02FCA3F0>
Going to <function view_profile at 0x02FCA4F0>
```

view_profile is a function in a completely different app.

Comment: what's so unbearable about decorators.login_required() and decorators.permission_required() ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two patterns:

```
(r'profile/$', login_required(profile,'student')),
(r'editprofile/$', login_required(editprofile,'student')),
```

Both match `http://your-site/student/editprofile`.

Try:

```
(r'^profile/$', login_required(profile,'student')),
(r'^editprofile/$', login_required(editprofile,'student')),
```

Django uses the view who's pattern matches first ([see number 3 here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)).

Comment: THIS was the issue.  I thought that because this urls.py was being include in another urls.py, that I WOULDN'T use the '^' in front but in turns out I need to.   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you can't use the standard @login_required decorator - it seems that your version actually provides *less* functionality, given that it always redirects to `\`, rather than the actual login view.

In any case, the reason why both are printed is because the `print` statement is in the top level of the decorator, and thus is executed when the urlconf is *evaluated*. If you put it in the inner `new_view` function, it will only be executed when it is actually called, and should print only the relevant view name.

Comment: you were right about the print statement, however why is the wrong view still being returned for editprofile

Answer (score 1):

Your `login_required` looks like it's a python decorator. Any reason you need to have it in your urls.py?

I think the `print 'Going to '+str(view)` line is getting evaluated when `urlpatterns` is read to determine which view to execute. It looks weird, but I don't think it'll hurt you.

The line `print 'Going to '+str(view)` will not be executed every time the view is hit, only when the url pattern is evaluated (I think). The code in `new_view` is the only code that will execute for certain as part of the view.

Comment: Maybe I can just use it as a decorator.  But even still...ok, you were right about the new_view only getting executed but why does the wrong view get loaded when I try editprofile